# Validation rules and functions

Tags: validation, cakephp, model, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have a cakephp 2.1 validation rule in the model

```
 'name' => array(

                'empty' => array(
                  'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                  'required' => true,
                  'allowEmpty' => false,
                  'message' => 'Name is required.'
                ),
                'unique' => array(
                'rule' => 'checkUnique',
                'required' => true,
                'allowEmpty' => false,
                'message' => 'Name already exists.'
                )
              )
```

I have the following code for te checkUnique method:

```
  public function checkUnique($data)
  {
//App::import('Model','User');
// $this->User = & new User();


if(empty($this->data['TeacherLocation']['id']))
{
    $locationInfo = $this->find
    (
        'all',
        array
        (
            'conditions'=>array
            (
                'user_id' => $this->data['TeacherLocation']['user_id'],
                'name' => $this->data['TeacherLocation']['name']
            ),
            'recursive' => -1
        )
    );

    return (empty($locationInfo));
```

But I keep getting an error on unable to find index user_id. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

so basically you want to check isUnique based on additional fields, right?

try my validateUnique method:
https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/2.0/Lib/MyModel.php#L818

so you got:

```
     'name' => array(
         ...
         'unique' => array(
            'rule' => array('validateUnique', array('user_id')),
            'required' => true,
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'message' => 'Name already exists.'
         )
      )
```

your problem seems to be that your validation method gets triggered even if there is no user_id in your passed data.

Answer (score 0):

isUnique is already built in to cake:

```
'name' => array(
    'isUnique' => array(
        'rule' => array('isUnique'),
        'message' => 'Name already exists',
    ),
```